# How to get the "About" information to display when creating a Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am developing a custom Wordpress theme and I need a space where I can display the about information. When I say the about information I mean information about the particular blog or site, not about the theme or me as a developer.

For example if the theme was applied to a blog for a hot dog stand the about information would say "We are Hot Dogs Empire, established in 1991 in Greenville ...".

I know there are a few wordpress theme functions like get_header and get_footer, I'm wondering if there is a function like this that would allow me to write my template for the theme so that whenever it is applied to a blog the blogs about information will be displayed in a certain space?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about `$blogdescription = get_option('blogdescription');` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this if the blog description is set:

```
$bloginfo = get_bloginfo( "description", "raw" );
```

This returns the "Tagline" set in `Settings > General`. This data is retrieved from the `blogdescription` record in the `wp_options` table.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with wordpress settings API https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API.

Description from wordpress:

```
The Settings API allows admin pages containing settings forms to be managed 
semi-automatically. It lets you define settings pages, sections within those 
pages and fields within the sections.
```